# How to permanently display the Touch Bar from one specific app when running?

Tags: node.js, macos, electron, nstouchbar, macbookpro-touch-bar

I've developed an app based on NodeJS with Electron for a web agency and try to extend it to the touch bar functionality of the MacBook Pro.

Developers launch the app once, which then automatically starts various processes in the background, such as compiling SASS files, optimizing images, etc.

Typically, these developers work with programs such as SublimeText or Atom. However, it often happens that the app expects user input during programming or inserts hints to optimize the code. I would like to display these things in the Touch Bar so that the user does not have to switch between the apps during programming. Unfortunately, the touch bar view of my app is hidden when switching to SublimeText or another app and replaced by the current app in the foreground.

Is there a way to display an app's specific touch bar while the app is running (even hidden) permanently without replacing it? I wonder if that is at least natively possible?

I couldn't find any information about this on the [Electron documentary](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/touch-bar.md) or somewhere else…

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I highly doubt it's possible - say you have app `a` tries to do it and another `b` do the same thing, what'll end up on user's touchbar?

Comment: hmm… you're right... I guess that would lead to a big mess on the touch bar…